# Laravel Query Builder joining with alias

Tags: sql, laravel, alias, laravel-6

I have two tables

Unknown table

```
id | parent_id
```

Clients table

```
id | parent_id
```

My Code :

```
$transaction = DB::table($name.'_transactions')
                    ->where('user_id', $id)
                    ->join('users', 'users.id' , '=' , 'parent_id')
                    ->get();
```

Joining will be with the `clients.id` => `unknown.parent_id`... As because the clients table has a `parent_id` that's why i have to use the alias

Please Help me to do so!

Comment: what is this $name.'_transactions'? is it a table? and if it is a table, what the foreign key to clients table?

Comment: yes! its a table coming dynamically.. And the relation will be `clients.id` => `unknown.parent_id`

Comment: have you tried:
->join('clients', 'clients.id' , '=' , $name.'parent_id')

Comment: yes! not worked maybe have to use alias

Comment: actually it works ! i missed something btw thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Alias Working Solution:

```
$tablename = Roles::where('id', '=' , 6)->first();
                    $name = str_replace(' ', '_', trim($tablename->name));
                    $tb = $name.'_transactions';
                    $exist_in_db = DB::table($tb)
                                        ->where('user_id', $id)
                                        ->get();
                    if(count($exist_in_db) > 0) {
                        $transaction = DB::table("$tb as newtable")
                                        ->where('user_id', $id)
                                        ->join('users', 'users.id' , '=' , 'newtable.parent_id')
                                        ->get();
```